# React native doesn't re-render with all new states

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, native

i am building a register form and i encountered a problem. After the user completes the fields, i do a validation check with regex. Every validation function will set an error message. Even though i intentionally trigger all those errors, only one will appear if i submit the form. Here is my code:

```
function RegisterScreen(): JSX.Element{


    const pwInput = React.createRef();
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
    const [birthday, setBirthday] = useState<Date | null>(null);
    const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState(false); 
    const [openTerms, setOpenTerms] = useState(false);
    const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [passError, setPassError] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [confPassError, setConfPassError] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [isTermsChecked, setIsTermsChecked] = useState<string | null>(null); 
   

    function _validateEmail(): boolean{
        const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if(re.test(email))
            return true;
        else{
            setEmailError(RegisterErrors.emailError);
            return false;
        }
       
    }
    function _validatePw(): boolean{
        const re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/
        
        if(re.test(password)) return true;
        else{
            setPassError(RegisterErrors.pwWeak);
            return false
        }
    }
    function _pwMatch(): boolean{

        if(password == confirmPassword){
            
            return true;
        }else{
            setConfPassError(RegisterErrors.pwConfirmMatchError);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function _validateAge(): boolean{
            return true;
    }

    function _validateTermsAndCond(): boolean{
            return true;
    } 

   

    function validateFieldsAndRegister(){

        console.log(email);
        console.log(password);
        console.log(confirmPassword);
        
        if( _validateEmail() && _validatePw() && _validateAge() && _validateTermsAndCond() && _pwMatch()){

                //trimite la firebase
                console.log("okay")

        }else{

           console.log('wrong fields')

            
        }

    }


  return(
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
     
        <ScrollView>
        <View style = {{flex:1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"center",backgroundColor:"white"}}>
        
        <TermsAndConditions open = {openTerms} close = { ()=>setOpenTerms(false) }/>
    
        <Image source={require("../../images/logoR.png")} style={styles.logoImg}/>
        

        <Text style={styles.mainText}>Register</Text>
        


        
          <Input  
            containerStyle={styles.inputView}
            inputContainerStyle={{backgroundColor:"white"}}
            placeholder="First Name..." 
            placeholderTextColor="rgb(0,0,0)"
            errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
            onChangeText={text => setFirstName(text)}/>
        
      
          <Input  
            containerStyle={styles.inputView}
            placeholder="Last Name..." 
            placeholderTextColor="rgb(0,0,0)"
            errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
            onChangeText={text => setLastName(text)}/>
        
       
        
          <Input 
            onFocus={()=>{setPassError(null)}}
            
            secureTextEntry
            containerStyle={styles.inputView}
            placeholder="Password..." 
            placeholderTextColor="rgb(0,0,0)" 
            errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
            errorMessage={passError}
            onChangeText={text =>setPassword(text)}/>
       

      
          <Input  
            secureTextEntry
            onFocus = {()=>{setConfPassError(null)}}
            containerStyle={styles.inputView}
            placeholder="Confirm Password..." 
            placeholderTextColor="rgb(0,0,0)"
            errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
            errorMessage={confPassError}
            
            onChangeText={text =>setConfirmPassword(text)}/>
      

       
          <Input  
            containerStyle={styles.inputView}
            onFocus={()=>{setEmailError(null)}}
            placeholder="Email..." 
            placeholderTextColor="rgb(0,0,0)"
            errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
            errorMessage={emailError}
            
            onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}/>
       

         
        <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
            <CheckBox
            value={isSelected}
            onValueChange={()=>{setSelection(!isSelected)}}
            style={styles.checkbox}
          
            />
    
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=> {setOpenTerms(true);}}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Terms and Conditions</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity  style={{...styles.inputView, ...styles.regBtnContainer}} onPress = {()=>{validateFieldsAndRegister()}}>
            <Text style = {styles.txtRegBtn}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        

        </View>
        
</ScrollView>

</SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3UVO.jpg)

If i invoke the validation functions before the if statement in validateFieldsAndRegister it will work. Errors will appear to the 3 fields.

Here are the errors i show

```
export const RegisterErrors = {

    emailError: "You must enter a valid email",
    pwConfirmMatchError:"The passwords you entered are not the same",
    termsAndCondError:"You must read and agree with the Terms and Conditions",
    birthdayError:"You must be 21 or older",
    pwWeak:"Your password must contain: a lowercase letter, a acapital letter, a number and minimum 8 characters"

}
```

Comment: Have you taken the async nature of state updates into account? It may just be a race condition.

Comment: it looks like as soon as a validation function return false the rest are not executed because there is no point in doing that.. the overall result will be false since i am using AND operator. Is this a thing in typescript/javascript?

Comment: Yes, JS will short-circuit.

Comment: It's a javascript thing [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet illustrating some of what is happening. It illustrates three different strategies for updating state.

The first groups all three `setState()` calls into a single function call and doesn't use an `if()` statement to check the results. The state changes show immediately.

The second splits the updates into three separate calls to `async` functions which in turn `await` a timeout function before calling `setState()`. These calls are made as the OP is doing from within an `if()` statement. Each async function returns a Promise which is being evaluated as truthy and we see 'promise' logged to the console. The results from the timeouts then trickle in.

The third case is the closest to the OP's question. It also makes separate calls from within an `if()` statement but they are synchronous and return `false`. The first call completes it's `setState()` call, returns false and halts further calls from inside the if. Because state has changed React calls a render and we see the single state change.

The upshot of all this is that it seems best to either make the validation calls before the `if()` statement, or better yet, collect all the validation results and then group all the `setState()` calls into a single function. This will allow React to more efficiently group these changes and call as few renders as possible.

(sorry for the cluttered snippet, the built in babel doesn't seem to handle `async/await`)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  
}
.example {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
button {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  const { useState } = React
  
  function App() {
  const [stateOne, setStateOne] = useState(1);
  const [stateTwo, setStateTwo] = useState(1);
  const [stateThree, setStateThree] = useState(1);
  
  const cycleStateSingle = () => {
    setStateOne((state) => state + 1);
    setStateTwo((state) => state + 1);
    setStateThree((state) => state + 1);
  }
  
  const [stateOnePromise, setStateOnePromise] = useState(1);
  const [stateTwoPromise, setStateTwoPromise] = useState(1);
  const [stateThreePromise, setStateThreePromise] = useState(1);
  
  const cycleOne = async () => {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      setStateOnePromise((state) => state + 1);
  }
  
  const cycleTwo = async () =>{
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      setStateTwoPromise((state) => state + 1);
  }
  
  const cycleThree = async () =>{
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
      setStateThreePromise((state) => state + 1);
  }
  
  const cycleStatePromise = () => {
    if (cycleOne(true) && cycleTwo(true) && cycleThree(true)) {
      console.log('promise');
    }
  }
  
  const [stateOneStepped, setStateOneStepped] = useState(1);
  const [stateTwoStepped, setStateTwoStepped] = useState(1);
  const [stateThreeStepped, setStateThreeStepped] = useState(1);
  
  const cycleOneStepped = () => {
      setStateOneStepped((state) => state + 1);
      return false;
  }
  
  const cycleTwoStepped = () =>{
      setStateTwoStepped((state) => state + 1);
      return false;
  }
  
  const cycleThreeStepped = () =>{
    setStateThreeStepped((state) => state + 1);
    return false;
  }
  
  const cycleStateStepped = () => {
    if (cycleOneStepped() && cycleTwoStepped() && cycleThreeStepped()) {
      console.log('stepped');
    }
  }
  
  return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="example">
      <div className="state-1">State 1: {stateOne}</div>
      <div className="state-2">State 2: {stateTwo}</div>
      <div className="state-3">State 3: {stateThree}</div>
      <button type="button" onClick={cycleStateSingle}>Single State Change</button>
    </div>
    <div className="example">
      <div className="state-1">State 1: {stateOnePromise}</div>
      <div className="state-2">State 2: {stateTwoPromise}</div>
      <div className="state-3">State 3: {stateThreePromise}</div>
      <button type="button" onClick={cycleStatePromise}>Promise State Change</button>
    </div>
    <div className="example">
      <div className="state-1">State 1: {stateOneStepped}</div>
      <div className="state-2">State 2: {stateTwoStepped}</div>
      <div className="state-3">State 3: {stateThreeStepped}</div>
      <button type="button" onClick={cycleStateStepped}>Stepped State Change</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>

<div id="root"></div>
```